# Backup DB from docker to real machine

Tags: mysql, database, docker, localhost, backup

**SOLVED !**

Good morning :)

Did anyone make a db backup from docker to host machine? I have a MySQL database but I would like to clone it into my real machine because every time I run container it creates a new image, but I want to use this db every time (so I want db to persist in real machine).

Thanks a lot !

[image]

Comment: have you create volumen to persist db data?

Comment: No , I think is what I really need no?, I need something to save my db when docker-compose down or I shutdown my computer...

Comment: So you need this https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes to restore your db after computer restart

Comment: That is great, thank you a lot, but I need a copy in my local machine too, I think is here below answered :)

Comment: Yes, but why you need a copy in your local machine? Do you need a sql dump or you want only to persist db (it is that volume does)?

Comment: Yes volume works perfectly :) but I would like a dump too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a Docker container that is already configured to use a MySQL database inside the container, you can make a database backup with the `mysqldump` inside the container, like this:

```
mysqldump database > database.sql
```

(NOTE! You run this inside your container)

You can then use the `docker container cp` command to copy files between the container and the local filesystem. For instance:

```
docker container cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```

(NOTE! You run this in your local filesystem)

So using this example, the commandline would become:

```
docker container cp <containerId>:/full/path/to/database.sql .
```

That copies the file `database.sql` to your current directory in your local filesystem.

Comment: I'm having a problem with container I think, data is on phpMyAdmin but i cannot find mysql db container IP so I cannot connect , any idea? I'm pasting an image

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it worked for me :) but I don't know how to connect through workbench for example because I cannot find that container IP, I give you the correct answer but I hope you know how to solve that problem finding container IP.

Comment: you have to publish db port and from host you will connect by `localhost:published_db_port`